# How to fix ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage issue after review?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I am trying to submit my app to AppStore and getting this error:

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: __availability_version_check. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Thank you!